# Update returns true but does not update db

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

i have an update function that updates a specific row in the table. The sql query works in PHPmyadmin and I am always returned true on the function. However, the database is not updated. I looked over the code and nothing appears wrong. What could be the problem. `primary_id` is the primary id of the table and the only other column is `fund_max`.

```
function change_fund_max ($mysqli, $project_id, $fund_max) {

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `project_fund_max` SET `fund_max` = ? WHERE 
    `project_id` = ?")){
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $project_id, $fund_max);
    $return = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    return $return;
} else {return false;}      

}
```

Here is the use of the function.

```
$fund_max = 11.55;
$project_id = 1;
$row43 =  change_fund_max ($mysqli, $project_id, $fund_max);
var_dump($row43);
```

Comment: Doubt it is your issue but quoting the column names is probably not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execute will only return `false` on a *failure*... like you messed up the SQL or something.  What you really want to know is did the command actually update on the rows... check [`mysqli_stmt_affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.affected-rows.php) to see if more than zero rows where changed.

Also your `project_id` and `fund_max` parameters are the wrong way around in your `bind` ;)

Result:

```
function change_fund_max ($mysqli, $project_id, $fund_max) {
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE `project_fund_max` SET `fund_max`=? WHERE 
     `project_id` = ?")){
     $stmt->bind_param('di', $fund_max, $project_id);
     if (!$stmt->execute()) return false;
     $count=$stmt->affected_rows;
     $stmt->close();
     return ($count>0);
  } else {
     return false;
  }
}
```

**Update:** For sneaky "fund_max is a decimal" comment... if fund_max is a decimal you need to bind to a double otherwise you're loosing anything right of the decimal place during the `bind_param` command (my code updated)

Comment: It's certainly the issue with this example ;)  Depends on if this was a fragment for the question or copied verbatim :D

Comment: I copied your function verbatim. Still returned `true` and no update on the server. I'll post the actual use of the function to see if that is the problem.

Comment: Ahh I never knew about the d in the bind_param. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess, but it seems the value passed in `$project_id` does not exist in the database.

That would make the `UPDATE` command run, not fail, but also not update any record.

Answer (score 1):

another guess, `project_id` and/or `fund_max` may not be both integers. you may check in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Also, the names of the columns shouldn't be surrounded by quotes(`), unless its present in the name itself, in the update query.

**Edit:**

```
function change_fund_max ($mysqli, $project_id, $fund_max) {

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE project_fund_max SET fund_max = ? WHERE 
 project_id = ?")){
 $stmt->bind_param('di', $fund_max, $project_id);
 $return = $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->close();
 return $return;
}  else {return false;}      

}
```

Comment: `fund_max` is a decimal and `project_id` is an integer.

Comment: then it has to be `$stmt->bind_param('di', $fund_max, $project_id);` to correspond to your query.